# How to remove dropCollection access right from users in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, user-accounts, drop-table

Created a MongoDB user with `readWrite` access to a collection. But I don't want to give `dropCollection` access right to that user. How can I implement that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [define your custom role](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-roles-collection/) for your purpose.

You can also extend existing roles, by inheriting with the `admin.system.roles.roles` field of your custom role.

Here is an example custom role

```
{
  role: "YourRole",
  db: "YourDatabase",
  privileges:
      [
          {
              resource: {db: "YourDatabase", collection: "OneOfCollections"},
              actions: ["find", "insert", "update", "remove", "createIndex" ...]
          },
          {
              resource: {db: "YourDatabase", collection: "AnotherCollection"},
              actions: ["find", "insert", "update", "remove", "createIndex" ...]
          },
          .
          .
          .
      ],
  roles:
      [
          { role: "RoleYouWantToInherit", db: "TheDatabaseRoleIsDefinedFor" },
          ...
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@n9code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3264192/n9code).

Running following query on admin collection gives an error.

```
db.runCommand({
    createRole:"mynew",
    priviliges : [..],
    roles: [
    { role: "read", db: "admin" }
  ],
  writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
})
```

**showing "error msg:no such cmd creareRole"**

Comment: Hi Bhargav - I think you must have made a typo in your command, `creareRole` should be `createRole`.
In any case, this isn't really an answer to the question; it's more of a comment on n9code's answer, so it should go there if anywhere.